# What's the difference between casking and kegging?

Tags: techniques, kegging, force-carbonation

So this is how my last beer went:

After about three weeks I threw it straight into a keg.  It didn't taste great, but I figured it was still young and just needed more time to condition.  A few weeks later I had something decent and realized that I had never force carbed it.  Over the month that that it took to drink the beer, maybe once or twice I gassed it to push out an extra glass or two when it sluggish and I was still thirsty, but the vast majority of the CO2 came from the yeast itself, not from my tank.  I called it my "cask" but I know it wasn't the real thing, right?  I mean, I certainly never sprang for a firkin.

But isn't that the difference between a Cask Beer and a Keg Beer - the force carbing?  So was it a cask beer?

And besides the nomenclature, is anything from the above description bad policy?

Answer (score 3):

I think that it was served and conditioned like a cask beer from your description.  Generally a cask beer is primed rather than force carbed and served via gravity rather than being pushed out with CO2, which could be absorbed by the beer.  That sounds like what you did.

Comment: Agreed.  You've got to get the timing correct to do what you did, and often serving temperatures are not condusive to appropritate yeast activity.  The cask beer process is a lot like bottling (including priming and letting the yeast go to town in the sealed vessel).  But a true cask is only good for three days max after tapping because it gets stale (air comes in through the vent).